# Pink, no texture, indicator when noise/voronoi or other textures are input into bump map height

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, bump

I've been following a number of youtube tutorials (old and new) on the topic of making cement, stone, and plaster.
Like this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FCJa97F9ReM&t=239s.

However when it comes to inputting a noise, voronoi or musgrave texture into the bump map height i get the pink no texture indicator.

Is there something i am doing wrong? Here are some pics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even node tree is weird for me, I can't reproduce your issue with today experimental build 2.91 https://imgur.com/W1xtLaB

Comment: Do you confirm all is ok just before connecting the bump to PBSDF normal?

Comment: Yes all is ok (to my limited understanding) before i input the texture to the bump height.

Comment: OK. So if this became pink just after the bump link, I think this is not a Voronoi issue and more likely gpu issue. What is you graphics card?

Comment: I has a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 960M

Comment: This card is supported I think. But could you check the cuda kernel version: should be 3.0 or above. (maybe wrong but procedural texture should not involve this pink color, imho).

Comment: I got a Cuda 11.1.70 driver

Comment: Don't know about the driver version, but you need to check the Cuda version (3.0 or above). https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#cuda

Comment: The unexpected had happened. Somehow (i think when i restored factory settings) my Geforce driver update became uninstalled. It appears the bump is working again after a new driver installation. Thanks all!